# Why is C++ heap allocation so slow compared to Java's heap allocation?

Tags: java, c++, performance, heap-memory, allocation

I ran small tests in Java and C++, creating tons of very small objects (no class members, nothing in constructors) and Java is clearly faster (I mean C++ seems to be really slow). I bet this has to do with the JVM but in which way ?

Edit:

The classes I used were like this (as I said no class members, nothing done in constructors) in C++ :

```
class foo{
    public:
        foo(){}
        ~foo(){}
}
```

And in Java :

```
public class Foo{
    public Foo(){}
}
```

The small tests I made were only about allocating tons of objects in a loop (arround 1000000000 in a row). I used GCC 4.7.2 and Java 1.7 through OpenJDK implementation, both on the same machine using Linux.

I bet that indeed it has to do with memory pool allocation, which indicates that the JVM owns uneeded memory.

I'm still confused because I thought JVM would actually be slower, counting pointers references and allocating memory.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. It depends on the C++ compiler, the JVM version, the benchmark programs, the platform, ...

Comment: Hotspot (which I assume you're using) is an optimising runtime. Object memory allocation is now so fast, it's considered nigh on free. However, I haven't seen your C++ code or which compiler implementation you're using so I can't comment on how optimal it is.

Comment: You are not comparing apples to apples here. JVM uses a pre-allocated memory pool for this situation. C++ has no pre-built functionality for such a construct and instead queries the OS memory manager for _every_ allocation. It's not uncommon for people to write a system that provides what JVM does here (a memory pool allocator) in C++. Also, this is a legit question and all the downvotes are BS.

Comment: Although it *could* benefit from a little more detail about the specific implementations tested and the testing done on them, this is a mostly reasonable question -- in particular, although there's some variation, implementations of the two languages are homogeneous enough for the question to be answerable with only minor caveats.

Comment: @Dave I don't think typical C++ implementations ask the OS for every allocation. `malloc` and `new` have many constraints which make many optimizations infeasible, but at the very least a C or C++ runtime library can allocate bigger slabs of memory from the OS and hand out chunks of that for most allocations.

Comment: I admit I was a bit short on details here, but thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Allocation of many small objects on the heap is one situation where Java's runtime is often better optimized out-of-the-box than C++ (in most mainstream implementations).  Every time you allocate a heap object in C++ using `new`, the implementation will usually make a system call to the OS (at least on most mainstream platforms like Linux and Windows).  In Java, it is usually allocating from a memory pool provided by the JVM, which is specially designed and optimized for allocating Java objects on the heap.

C++ will likely be faster in most situations if you use a special memory pool allocator.  (Also, C++ gives you the option to allocate objects on the stack, which, of course, is much faster than any of this.)

In general, C++ gives you much more fine-grained control over how your program allocates and manages memory.  Whereas JVMs are constrained by the actual Java language spec which [requires heap-allocated objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3) and garbage collection.  But if you're writing an application in C++ that needs to allocate many small objects on the heap, you might want to consider using a memory pool allocator.